# How do I update multiple records in the same table with one sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hey I was wondering if I could get some help with this:

```
Select q1.questionid, qa.questionanswergroupid
from questions q1
full join Questions_AnswerGroup qa on qa.QuestionId=q1.QuestionId
and qa.QuestionId=q1.QuestionId where q1.sectionid=7610
and q1.questiontext like 'Date Filed with EMMA%'
```

This gets me this:

```
    questionid  questionanswergroupid
    31164            17133
    31164            17464
    31164            17465
    31164            17466
    31164            17467
    31164            17468
    31164            17469
    31164            17470
    31169            (null)
    31173            (null)
    31177            (null)
    31181            (null)
    31185            (null)
    31189            (null)
    31193            (null)
```

THis is where I want to be:

```
Row questionid  questionanswergroupid
    31164            17133
    31169            17464
    31173            17465
    31177            17466
    31181            17467
    31185            17468
    31189            17469
    31193            17470
```

Thanks for any help in advance. i would like to have a singular update statement that replaces the duplicate questionids in Questions_AnswerGroup with the uniquie values from the questions table that have no corresponding value in the Questions_AnswerGroup tabel.

Comment: Your sample output isn't possible - there is no `Row` referenced in the query. Also, do you want to delete the rows 9-15, or leave them as is?

Comment: Sorry copied the result set numbering. The records where the null values don't exist.

Comment: So, what you're trying to do is to go through all the rows that have more than one `questionid` with a valid `questionanswergroupid`, and extract those `questionanswergroupid` (the ones after the first, presumably valid one) and instead pair them up with `questionid`'s that are in your table but have a null `questionanswerid`?

Comment: How can you even be sure there will be enough questionanswergroupid values to replace the nulls?

Comment: Could you provide source tables example?

Answer (score 1):

use an inner join 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: This doesnt replace the questionids but it does give me a result set without the nulls. My intended result is to replace the duplicate questionids with the uniquie ones that have no corresponding value in the questionanswergroupid column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select q1.questionid, qa.questionanswergroupid 
from questions q1 
full join Questions_AnswerGroup qa on qa.QuestionId=q1.QuestionId 
and qa.QuestionId=q1.QuestionId where q1.sectionid=7610 
and q1.questiontext like 'Date Filed with EMMA%' and qa.questionanswergroupid is not null
```

Comment: This doesnt replace the questionids but it does give me a result set without the nulls. My intended result is to replace the duplicate questionids with the uniquie ones that have no corresponding value in the questionanswergroupid column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this..

First `CREATE FUNCTION` called `FindUniqueQuestionId` fired with param `@questionanswergroupid`

Second do:

```
UPDATE Questions_AnswerGroup
SET QuestionId = FindUniqueQuestionId(questionanswergroupid)
WHERE questionanswergroupid IN 
(
  SELECT questionanswergroupid FROM Questions_AnswerGroup WHERE "is duplicate" -- pseudo code
)
```